# Create nested stored procedure call to send a uniform result set to Entity Framework

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, t-sql, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on converting a web forms project to an ASP.NET MVC 4 project.

In this project we the .NET team are not allowed to modify the existing stored procedures, at max we are allowed to write a wrapper for this stored procedure. I.e. We can create an another stored procedure which calls the existing ones.

The existing stored procedure is of the following type

```
condition 1
  Select A,B,C,D from Table
condition 2
  Select ErrorCode as 100, ErrorMessage as 'Correct that'
condition 3
  Select ErrorCode as 101, ErrorMessage as 'Correct this'
condition 4
  Select ErrorCode as 102, ErrorMessage as 'Not found' from Table
```

And I am using Entity Framework in this project which requires a complex type to be pre-mapped so for the above type of stored procedure I have declared a complex type as

```
Complex Type :- SomeComplexType

    string A;
    string B;
    string C;
    string D;

    int ErrorCode;
    string ErrorMessage;
```

Now my **problem** is lack of SQL knowledge and syntax, I have been searching a lot on the google and SO, but was not able to find anything on this.

I want to know how to create a wrapper around this existing stored procedure, some thing like the one below.

```
condition 1
  Select A,B,C,D,ErrorCode as NULL, ErrorMessage as NULL from Table
condition 2
  Select A,B,C,D,ErrorCode as 100, ErrorMessage as 'Correct that' from Table
condition 3
  Select A,B,C,D,ErrorCode as 101, ErrorMessage as 'Correct this' from Table
condition 4
  Select A as NULL, B as NULL, C as NULL, D as NULL,ErrorCode as 102, ErrorMessage as 'Not found' from Table
```

So if I am able to send data from SQL like shown above I can then handle it easily using Entity Framework's function import and complex type.

**How do I check (in the wrapper stored procedure) what result set is returned (from the existing stored procedure)?**

Please guide me with ideas on this. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

edit:
old post was not helping, adding some more info just to help in the search:

ok, I googled a bit and I really can't find any way to solve your problem; though i found some useful links:

[How to Share Data between Stored Procedures](http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html)
and
[Insert results of a stored procedure into a temporary table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653714/how-to-select-into-temp-table-from-stored-procedure)

I was hoping that the second one would've been useful but when i tried the `OPENROWSET` i got this error:

> The metadata could not be determined because the statement 'SELECT
>   '1','2','3'' in procedure 'testSP' is not compatible with the
>   statement 'SELECT 100,200' in procedure 'testSP'.

so i suppose it's not the right way.

now, the only ideas I have left are:

- Rewrite the old SP instead of building a wrapper around
- Can you find a way to determine the returned resultset from the input values? if that is possible you can just use if / else to choose the appropriate columns for the temp table where you will insert the data and then build the complex datatype

I'm sorry that i couldn't help any better

edit (again):

the first [link](http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html) says (at the CLR chapter):

> As a recap, here are the main situations where INSERT-EXEC fails you,
>   and you would want to turn to the CLR:
>
> The called procedure returns several result sets with different
>   structures. This is true for many system procedures in SQL Server.

so i suggest you to read this [chapter](http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html#CLR), maybe it will be useful

Comment: yea I am doing it somewhat like this only, But how do I check what result set is returned ?

Comment: lol... the answer says `The only time when it really becomes difficult (and maybe impossible, I've never seen it done) is when the stored procedure returns multiple recordsets (not multiple records) and the recordsets have different fields.` which is exactly my case !

Comment: changed my answer, I hope it helps at least a little bit

Comment: Thanks for all info, This didn't help though, but I am up-voting your answer for your efforts.